# Promises in angularjs controller - how to implement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am trying to implement a basic function using promises in one of my controllers just so I can ensure it is working correctly before adding in more complex functionality. I am getting a "TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the ".then(function(data){" in the lockPromise method.

**Function called from view**

```
    $scope.lockPromise = function(fieldId) {
        $scope.getLockMessage2(fieldId).getWeather()
            .then(function(data) {
                if (data === "returned SUCCESS info") {
                    alert("data is good");
                } else {
                    alert("FAILED");
                }
            }, function(error) {
                alert(error);
            });
    };
```

**Second function in ctrl**

```
    $scope.getLockMessage2 = function(fieldId) {
        return{
            getWeather: function() {
                return $http.get('/api/getData')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        if (typeof response.data === "string") {
                            return response.data;
                        } else {
                            return $q.reject(response.data);
                        }
                    }, function(response) {
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    });
            }
        };
    };
```

**API GET**

```
[Route("api/getData")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
    {

        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("returned SUCCESS info");

        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
    }
```

**EDIT 1**:
code updated to reflect comments

Comment: That `2nd` function ought to be in a service page rather than inside controller for a start. Youre almost there, just need minor alterations where you `return data`. please see http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/

Comment: `$scope.getLockMessage2(fieldId).getWeather()` you are returning object and not function

Comment: @RoyMJ i was intending to put it in a service after testing - i know this is trivial but what is the necessity for it to be in service?

Comment: @HarishR thanks i updated the code to reflect this

Comment: @AlexScott it should work now.. have you checked

Comment: @HarishR yes it does, cheers dude, stupid mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$scope.getLockMessage2(fieldId).then
```

to

```
$scope.getLockMessage2(fieldId).getWeather().then
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $scope.getLockMessage2 return an object, not function.

I think the code should be (not tested):

```
$scope.lockPromise = function(fieldId) {
    $scope.getLockMessage2(fieldId).getWeather()
        .then(function(data) {
            if (data === "good") {
                alert("data is good");
            } else {
                alert("FAILED");
            }
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error);
        });
};
```